# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I'm just starting with deep learning and python and I'm already stuck with this error when I try to train the model.
I thought it would be an easy starting project to get together the basic building blocks, but I obviously haven't grasped some basics..
My goal is to train a model on a data set of 5 column values `'1ex','2ex','3ex','4ex','5ex'` and predict sequences of 5 values.

I'm reading the dataset from a csv file i generated and it's displaying as expected.

Can you help me understanding what I'm missing out?
Thank you very much as always.
This is the code I've written so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

from collections import deque
import random

# load the data set
df = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=['Wheel','Date','1ex','2ex','3ex','4ex','5ex'])

# divide it into portions

times = sorted(df.index.values)  # get the times
last_10pct = sorted(df.index.values)[-int(0.1*len(times))]  # get the last 10% of the times
last_20pct = sorted(df.index.values)[-int(0.2*len(times))]  # get the last 20% of the times

test_df = df[(df.index >= last_10pct)]
validation_df = df[(df.index >= last_20pct) & (df.index < last_10pct)]  
train_df = df[(df.index < last_20pct)]  # now the train_df is all the data up to the last 20%

# drop 'Date' column
train_df.drop(columns=["Date"], inplace=True)
validation_df.drop(columns=["Date"], inplace=True)
test_df.drop(columns=["Date"], inplace=True)

# the model

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
# from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# define base model

def baseline_model():
#   scale = StandardScaler()
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(15, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(15, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer='normal', activation = softmax))
    # Compile model
#   model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
#   model.fit(train_df, epochs = 5)
    return model

# train the model

baseline_model.fit(train_df, batch_size=1, epochs=200, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you write `baseline_model`, it returns the function, not the result.

Therefore `baseline_model.fit` can't be called because `'function' object has no attribute 'fit'`

You must execute the function to get its result, using parentheses - `baseline_model()` - and then `fit` will be performed on the result. ;)

---

tl;dr:

`baseline_model.fit(` -> `baseline_model().fit(`

Comment: thanks.. I really couldn't see it hahah
Dough obviously Al kind of errors came up.. but at least now I can keep investigating and learning :)

Comment: It's sometimes hard to spot such errors because visually everything is there. And if someone is used to other languages, they don't always expect the function to be an object or expect type checking.

Comment: Absolutely, the other only language I know is Swift, and I still have to get used to the Python paradigm, that for certain aspect I actually prefer, but tis kind of things in Swift get checked by swift itself, which is a great help for typos or type related errors. Well..this can only make me a better developer by not having an automated checking system .. dough it means that I'll reach for help quite often..
Now that the model runs, I've seen that I have to get rid of another column in the data set as it's a string, but I'm not succeeding at it..hahah.. some index missing..

Comment: Some IDEs do some type checking for simpler things. You can also annotate your functions or add docstrings with parameters and their types to keep track of what should be what - and help your IDE with that type checking. ;)